# logging AD events when disabling an account via exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, user-accounts

I have been googleing around for a few days now trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly apprecited (links, hints, etc). Thanks!

**concept**

I want to generate an alert when an account is disabled from exchange.

**success**

I am able to generate an alert for windows event id 4725(A user account was disabled) when i disable an account in active directory on any of my domain controllers. I know this works. I have been doing it for months in this current environment.

**failure**

I am unable to generate an alert for a user account was disabled when i disable an account in exchange.

**questions**

does exchange tell AD that the account was disabled?
If it does, what event ID is it?
if it does not, why not? How would i log this going forward?

**network basics**

- exchange 2010
- windows server 2008r2
- I am a domain admin and exchange admin (i have any rights i need to do this)
- AD authentication is the standard
- ask me anything else you need

Comment: Could you detail how you are disabling the account from Exchange? If you're disabling from the UI, that just removes Exchange attributes from the AD account (leaving it enabled) and disconnects the mailbox.

Comment: I believe the admin did it from the gui. i just checked Ad users and the user account is disabled. I am not sure if both events happened at once though. I will ask the admin who did it and let you know the process asap.

Comment: i just heard back from my admin and he said "I was connected through RPD to Exchange2010 and used AD Users and Computers from that machine."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue using what you have been doing.  The account is disabled at the DC not at the Exchange Server regardless of where you are running ADUC.

Comment: Also consider adding the following to your procedure for disabling mailboxes:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/messaging_with_communications/archive/2012/06/27/part-ii-outlook-amp-owa-disabled-accounts-and-users-still-being-able-to-access.aspx